# Keeping track of mutated rows in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a large table whose rows get updated/inserted/merged periodically from a few different queries. I need a scheduled process to run (via API) to periodically check for which rows in that table were updated since the last check. So here are my issues...

- When I run the merge query, I don't see a way for it to return which records were updated... otherwise, I could be copying those updated rows to a special updated_records table.
- There are no triggers so I can't keep track of mutations that way.
- I could add a last_updated timestamp column to keep track that way, but then repeatedly querying the entire table all day for that would be a huge amount of data billed (expensive).

I'm wondering if I'm overlooking something obvious or if maybe there's some kind of special BQ metadata that could help?

The reason I'm attempting this is that I'm wanting to extract and synchronize a smaller subset of this table into my PostgreSQL instance because the latency for querying BQ is just too much for smaller queries.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did anyone solved your problem already??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some good ideas posted here. Thanks to those who responded. Essentially, there are multiple approaches to tackling this.

But anyway, here's how I solved my particular problem...

Suppose the data needs to ultimately end up in a table called *MyData*. I created two additional tables, *MyDataStaging* and *MyDataUpdate*. These two tables have an identical structure to *MyData* with the exception of *MyDataStaging* has an additional Timestamp field, "batch_timestamp". This timestamp allows me to determine which rows are the latest versions in case I end up with multiple versions before the table is processed.

DatFlow pushes data directly to *MyDataStaging*, along with a Timestamp ("batch_timestamp") value indicating when the process ran. 
A scheduled process then upserts/merges *MyDataStaging* to *MyDataUpdate* (*MyDataUpdate* will now always contain only a unique list of rows/values that have been changed). Then the process upserts/merges from *MyDataUpdate* into *MyData* as well as being exported & downloaded to be loaded into PostgreSQL. Then staging/update tables are emptied appropriately.

Now I'm not constantly querying the massive table to check for changes.

NOTE: When merging to the main big table, I filter the update on unique dates from within the source table to limit the bytes processed.

Answer (score 2):

An approach would be to have 3 tables:

1. one `basetable` in "append only" mode, only inserts are added, and updates as full row, in this table would be every record like a versioning system.
2. a table to hold `deletes` (or this can be incorporated as a soft delete if there is a special column kept in the first table)
3. a `livetable` where you hold the current data (in this table you would do your `MERGE` statements most probably from the first base table.

If you choose partitioning and clustering, you could end up leverage a lot for long time storage discounted price and scan less data by using partitioning and clustering.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. But I wonder if you are talking about something else I had been considering. Where the first table is essentially a staging table. All data coming in (inserts and updates) is stored here first. Once these rows have been both merged into the main table and processed for synchronizing with my external Postgres database, then those rows can be deleted. So this staging table is my 'changes' table and it is always kept relatively small... so scanning the entire table is not very expensive.  Does this sound similar to what you are describing?

Comment: After further thought, I think I just realized what you are saying. Something very similar to what I just described in my previous comment... but rather than deleting the already-processed records, you're talking about just maintaining a date_updated timestamp and querying on that partition.
Almost the same effect as what I described previously. 
Does that sound right?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you need to maintain the `basetable` as that will hold all the versions, you can write statements to get only the latest row. For that you need a `timestamp` and a partition id, probably and `ID` columns. I think you are close to get to a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to periodically save intermediate state of the table using the time travel feature. Or store only the diffs. I just want to leave this option here:

`FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` references the historical versions of the table definition and rows that were current at `timestamp_expression`.

The value of `timestamp_expression` has to be within **last 7 days**.

The following query returns a historical version of the table from one hour ago.

```
SELECT * FROM table
  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

The following query returns a historical version of the table at an absolute point in time.

```
SELECT * FROM table
  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2017-01-01 10:00:00-07:00';
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know you could do that. Very cool. But unfortunately, this solution leaves me with the same problem I describe my 3rd bullet point. That is, that it is too expensive for me to keep querying the entire table in this manner :( I think this could be a great solution otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If the table is large but the amount of data updated per day is modest then you can partition and/or cluster the table on the `last_updated_date` column. There are some edge cases, like the first today's check should filter for `last_updated_date` being either today or yesterday.

Depending of how modest this amount of data updated throughout a day is, even repeatedly querying the entire table all day could be affordable because BQ engine will scan one daily partition only.

**P.S.**
Detailed explanation

> I could add a last_updated timestamp column to keep track that way

I inferred from that the `last_updated` column is not there yet (so the check-for-updates statement cannot currently distinguish between updated rows and non-updated ones) but you can modify the table UPDATE statements so that this column will be added to the newly modified rows.

Therefore I assumed you can modify the updates further to set the additional  `last_updated_date` column which will contain the date portion of the timestamp stored in the `last_updated` column.

> but then repeatedly querying the entire table all day

From here I inferred there are multiple checks throughout the day.

> but the data being updated can be for any time frame

Sure, but as soon as a row is updated, no matter how old this row is, it will acquire two new columns `last_updated` and `last_updated_date` - unless both columns have already been added by the previous update in which cases the two columns will be updated rather than added. If there are several updates to the same row between the update checks, then the latest update will still make the row to be discoverable by the checks that use the logic described below.

The check-for-update statement will (conceptually, not literally):

- filter rows to ensure `last_updated_date=today AND last_updated>last_checked`. The datetime of the previous update check will be stored in `last_checked` and where this piece of data is held (table, durable config) is implementation dependent.
- discover if the current check is the first today's check. If so then additionally search for `last_updated_date=yesterday AND last_updated>last_checked`.

Note 1
If the table is partitioned and/or clustered on the `last_updated_date` column, then the above update checks will not cause table scan. And subject to ‘modest’ assumption made at the very beginning of my answer, the checks will satisfy your 3rd bullet point.

Note 2
The downside of this approach is that the checks for updates will not find rows that had been updated before the table UPDATE statements were modified to include the two extra columns. (Such rows will be in the`__NULL__` partition with rows that never were updated.) But I assume until the changes to the UPDATE statements are made it will be impossible to distinguish between updated rows and non-updated ones anyway.

Note 3
 This is an explanatory concept. In the real implementation you might need one extra column instead of two. And you will need to check which approach works better: partitioning or clustering (with partitioning on a fake column) or both.

The detailed explanation of the initial (e.g. above **P.S.**) answer ends here.

Note 4

> clustering only helps performance

From the point of view of table scan avoidance and achieving a reduction in the data usage/costs, clustering alone (with fake partitioning) could be as potent as partitioning.

Note 5
In the comment you mentioned there is already some partitioning in place. I’d suggest to examine if the existing partitioning is indispensable, can it be replaced with clustering.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But if I understand you correctly (and please correct me if I'm wrong), this doesn't really solve the cost problem I mention in my 3rd bullet point. This table is already partitioned, but the data being updated can be for any time frame. So, in order, to make sure I capture everything, I would have to scan the entire table every time regardless of partitions.  And as far as I can tell, clustering only helps performance. I think this is a good solution if you are confident that only recent data is being updated.

Comment: Added the P.S. part to the answer.